# Meaning of elastic energy formulation

Tags: condensed-matter, elasticity, spin-models

In Chaikin's Principles of Condensed Matter Physics, in chapter 6 ("Generalized Elasticity"), on pg. 290, there is a formulation of what he refers to as an elastic energy associated with gradients of a variable $\theta(x)$, where $x$ is a site on a lattice and $\theta$ the angle of the order parameter for spins aligning on the lattice. This energy is supposedly:
$$F_{el} = \frac{1}{2}\int d^{d}xp_{s}[\nabla\theta(x)]^2$$ This is derived by reasoning that the first order term drops and that the energy is a function of spatial variation in $\theta$. $\\$
My question is this: how does the integral of a vector (the gradient of the scalar field $\theta(x)$) that is squared (whatever that means) result in a scalar value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a scalar field $\theta(x)$, 
$$[\nabla\theta(x)]^2= \nabla \theta \cdot \nabla \theta = \left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z}\right)^2$$

is also a scalar field.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I wish dot products were not supplanted by exponents on occasion.